# Ignore [ScriptIgnore] Attribute in Inheriting Class

Tags: c#, scriptignore

I have a base class where a property has a ScriptIgnore attribute:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I also have another class which inherits from the Base class:

```
public class Inherting : Base
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I tried overriding the Name property but it is still not being serialized. Is there a way to override the ScriptIgnore attribute (ignore it in the inherting class)?

Comment: You mean you *do* want `ScriptIgnore` on the overridden property, or you don't? I believe overriding it makes the attribute of the virtual property useless, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @aevitas I want to ignore it in the inheriting class' overriding property. So if it's serialized, I want the Name property to be there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried overriding the Name property but it is still not being
>   serialized. Is there a way to override the ScriptIgnore attribute
>   (ignore it in the inherting class)?

Use `ScriptIgnore`'s `ApplyToOverrides` property and set it to `false`:

```
[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = false)]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

Reference: [ScriptIgnoreAttribute.ApplyToOverrides Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.applytooverrides(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried that but it's still not being serialized. So I set the ApplyToOverrides to false and it is now being serialized.

Comment: @dork I assume that false is the right answer, but the documentation at MSDN is pretty misleading about it. I changed my answer anyway.

Comment: Yup, very confusing. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know why `ApplyToOverrides` is not exists more? And what the alternative way to do it?

Comment: @mykhailovskyi It's exists in .net 4.5